# Lan card not recognizing connected cable

Tags: linux, ethernet

I have a system with Ubuntu Server 14.04 installed on it. The onboard ethernet port is faulty. As I want to setup DHCP server on it, I have installed two external LAN cards. I also have a leased line. When I plugin the cable directly into one of the lan cards, none of them recognize it. None of the lights turn on. If I plug this cable to a router and plug the output cable from the router to any of the Lan card, it works fine.

The cable when connected directly to my laptop works fine. In every case if the leased line cable is connected to any of the lan card on my server, it doesn't seem to work. Even the light don't turn up.

Can someone point me in a right direction.

Comment: What is the make/model of the cards you installed?

Comment: The card is Enter E-100E. The same card works when I connect a cable coming out of the router.

Comment: This is a PCI card? Not PCIe?!? How old is this server? It's likely that this card does not support Auto MDI-X, in which case you should trying connecting it using a crossover ethernet cable.

Comment: The card info says RTL-8100/810L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (rev 10). Looking at the box, I feel it is a PCI card.

The only issue is that the direct cable I have is from the leased line. I'm not sure how to make that a crossover cable.

Comment: @EEAA, is probably correct. If the router can do Auto MDI-X, a straight-through cable will work (only one end needs to do this), but if neither end does this, you probably need a crossover cable, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an *ancient* network card. From what I can tell, the RTL-81XX chipsets were released in 2001. That's **15** years ago. These chipsets do not appear to support Auto MDI-X, which supports my theory that you need a crossover cable. If you have a different, more modern system you could test with, connect the cable to that and see if you get link lights.

Your best bet is to purchase a modern network card that supports Auto MDI-X (which any network card made in the last 5-8 years will do).

If you can't do that, then you can re-terminate the cable from your provider as a crossover cable, but make sure you discuss this with your provider first.

Comment: The other option is that it is a crossover cable, and the link needs a straight-through.

Answer (score 0):

A good thing to have in your toolbox is a Crossover Adapter which can be bought from Amazon for like $5-$10. This device allows you to convert any standard cable to a crossover without modifying the existing cable. This would allow you to test your current device to see if it is a Auto-MDX issue as others seem to believe it is.

In either case you should certainly purchase updated hardware.